# How to Track Loading Progress While Fetching Data on Server Side in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, loading

I'm currently building a web application using Next.js and I need to fetch data from the server. I'm looking for guidance on how to implement a loading progress tracking mechanism during the data retrieval process on the server side. The goal is to enhance the user experience by displaying loading indicators or progress bars.

I've researched a bit and considered options like **`setTimeout`** function to create an artificial delay.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {

  // Simulate a delay to show loading progress
  const simulateDelay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  try {
    await simulateDelay(1000);

    // Fetch data
    const response = await axios.get('https://example-api/');
    const data = response.data;

    return {
      props: {
        data
      }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);

    return {
      props: {
        data: null 
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I'm sure this is not a good approach.

Are there any recommended practices within the Next.js ecosystem that can simplify the process of tracking loading progress while fetching data on the server side?

I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide code examples, step-by-step explanations, or insights based on their experience. Thank you in advance for your assistance!